# Select multiple from dropdown, single value passed

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been trying to edit a Wordpress template to my specific needs. The problem is, that by default, people can only select one option from a dropdown. I want them to be able to select 2 or more. At present, this functionality is in place from the admin panel, where I can select several values, but from the frontend, only one value can be selected.

```
<div class="form-option">
    <label for="type"><?php _e('Usage', 'framework'); ?></label>
    <span class="selectwrap">
        <select name="type" id="type" class="search-select">
            <option selected="selected" value="-1"><?php _e('Choose', 'framework'); ?></option>
            <?php
            /* Property Type */
            $property_types_terms = get_terms(
                array(
                    "property-type"
                ),
                array(
                    'orderby'    => 'name',
                    'order'      => 'ASC',
                    'hide_empty' => false,
                    'parent'     => 0
                )
            );
            generate_id_based_hirarchical_options("property-type", $property_types_terms, -1 );
            ?>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Based on this code snippet, can anyone give me a hint  as to what can be done? I've tried adding multiple to the select, and while this does allow several selections, only the last selection picked is passed to the database.

Maybe this code is the problem?

```
// Attach Property Type with Newly Created Property
            if( isset( $_POST['type'] ) && ( $_POST['type'] != "-1" ) ) {
                wp_set_object_terms( $property_id, intval( $_POST['type'] ), 'property-type' );
            }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `multiple` missing on `<select name="type" id="type" class="search-select">` and name should be `type[]`.

Comment: I've tried adding multiple on the select, and while this does make selecting several values possible, only the last chosen value is passed to the database. I'm thinking, that the problem may be in the code, which passes the value(s) to the database.

Comment: Can you check the posted values? How they are posted as array or not

Comment: I've just updated my question with more code. I think the new code is where the value is passed to the database, and it looks like it only take a single value?

Comment: You need to change the select field name, as Sougata said - otherwise, PHP will overwrite the multiple values that are send and only preserve the last one.

Comment: Ahh, it's working now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick point in the right direction, you are passing an array to a variable, you need to assign the values to an array, then pick from the index.